# List DataModel reads just the last element

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a database created with location updates and in the database there is a bunch of locations x and y. and in the second method readFirestore() reads the location data and compares the favorite locations which came from sqlite database and if the favorite location is near the data from firestore it writes the campaign name which is on the same location to another database. But when I want to compare the favorite location in the firestore methot, there is just the last item of the database. I looked with the Log.

Code 1:

```
public List<DataModel> listFavoriteLocation(){
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase mydb = db.getWritableDatabase();
    List<DataModel> data=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor csr = mydb.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE+" ;",null);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    DataModel dataModel = null;
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        dataModel= new DataModel();
        String FAVCurrentLocationLAT = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FAVCurrentLocationLAT"));
        String FAVCurrentLocationLONG = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FAVCurrentLocationLONG"));
        dataModel.setFAVCurrentLocationLAT(FAVCurrentLocationLAT);
        dataModel.setFAVCurrentLocationLONG(FAVCurrentLocationLONG);
        stringBuffer.append(dataModel);
        data.add(dataModel);

    }
    for (DataModel mo:data ) {
        this.List_FAVCurrentLocationLAT = mo.getFAVCurrentLocationLAT();
        this.List_FAVCurrentLocationLONG = mo.getFAVCurrentLocationLONG();
         Log.i("helloLAT",""+List_FAVCurrentLocationLAT); //OK
         Log.i("helloLONG",""+List_FAVCurrentLocationLONG); //OK
    // This section writes the favorite locations seperately to the log. 
     }
    return data;
}
```

Code 2:

```
public void readFirestore() {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("campaigns")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                private String FSname,FScityLAT,FScityLONG,FScampaignStartDate,FScampaignEndDate;

                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            String name = document.getString("name");
                            String cityLAT = document.getString("cityLAT");
                            String cityLONG = document.getString("cityLONG");
                            String campaignStartDate = document.getString("campaignStartDate");
                            String campaignEndDate = document.getString("campaignEndDate");

                            this.FSname = name;
                            this.FScityLAT = cityLAT;
                            this.FScityLONG = cityLONG;
                            this.FScampaignStartDate = campaignStartDate;
                            this.FScampaignEndDate = campaignEndDate;

                            listFavoriteLocation();

                            String FS_FAVCurrentLocationLAT = List_FAVCurrentLocationLAT;
                            String FS_FAVCurrentLocationLONG = List_FAVCurrentLocationLONG;

                            Log.i("hellolist",""+List_FAVCurrentLocationLAT); // just writes the last loc item from sqlite

                            double FS_FAVCurrentLocationLAT_double = Double.parseDouble(FS_FAVCurrentLocationLAT); // Fav Loc DB
                            double FS_FAVCurrentLocationLONG_double = Double.parseDouble(FS_FAVCurrentLocationLONG);                                 double FScityLAT_double = Double.parseDouble(FScityLAT);  // Campaign Loc Firestore LAT
                            double FScityLONG_double = Double.parseDouble(FScityLONG);  

                            double theta = FScityLONG_double - FS_FAVCurrentLocationLONG_double;
                            double dist = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(FS_FAVCurrentLocationLAT_double)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(FScityLAT_double)) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(FS_FAVCurrentLocationLAT_double)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(FScityLAT_double)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
                            dist = Math.acos(dist);
                            dist = Math.toDegrees(dist);
                            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
                            dist = dist * 1.609344;

                            if (dist <= 0.5) // 500 meter
                            {
                                SQLiteQueryFavCampaign = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable3(FAVCampaignName, FAVCampaigncampaignStartDate, FAVCampaigncampaignEndDate)" + " VALUES('"+FSname+"','"+FScampaignStartDate+"','"+FScampaignEndDate+"');";
                                SQLITEDATABASEFavCampaign.execSQL(SQLiteQueryFavCampaign);
                                Log.i("helloname",""+FSname);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            });

    Toast.makeText(CampaignActivity.this,"Creating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly: the `listFavoriteLocation` method properly retrieves the data you're expecting from the database. If you take a look at the rest of your code, you'll see that you are iterating over the list of data and overwriting your instance variables with them, one-by-one, until the list has been fully iterated over, meaning you will only preserve the last element in your instance once you've left the method.

So, to be clear, the following block will properly log every element, but only the values of the last element will be preserved in the two instance variables you're using (`FAVCurrentLocationLAT` and `FavCurrentLocationLong`):

```
for (DataModel mo:data ) {
    this.List_FAVCurrentLocationLAT = mo.getFAVCurrentLocationLAT();
    this.List_FAVCurrentLocationLONG = mo.getFAVCurrentLocationLONG();
    Log.i("helloLAT",""+List_FAVCurrentLocationLAT); //OK
    Log.i("helloLONG",""+List_FAVCurrentLocationLONG); //OK
    // This section writes the favorite locations seperately to the log. 
}
```

What you need to do is use the returned `data` list being loaded in the `listFavoriteLocation` method, and then manipulate it in the following code as you wish.

So, for example:

```
List<DataModel> data = listFavoriteLocation();
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    DataModel dataModel = data.get(i);
    log.i("Data model "+i+": "+dataModel);
    // Do work on each data model element here
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you for your answer but I can read the data seperately in the first methot the list data model. But I can not reach the all data in readFirestore() in this method just the last element set in to the variables from list method.

Comment: @LBT Indeed. This is because the first method does not expose the data it is working with. So, to use it in your readFirestore method, you need to use the list it returns by assigning another reference to it. So, use `List<DataModel> data = listFavoriteLocation();` in your readFirestore method, and then you will have all of its data in that new list.